# Delete files in folder with 11 or more characters

Tags: windows, shell, file-io, cmd

I have text folders in a file `C:\TruncTest2`.  In the same folder I have a .bat file with the following code:

```
find -type f -name "???????????*" -delete
```

I am trying to delete files that have 11 or more characters in their file name.  This appears to be the correct solution when looking at other examples but nothing happens when I run the batch file.

Comment: Are you using cygwin?

Comment: Sorry I do not typically write DOS commands or create batch files and am trying to help a co-worker.  I am using Windows OS

Comment: First off, add a tag for MSWidows or MSDOS, or .bat files. Also there is a find command for DOS that is very different than the `find` cmd of *nix. I think you're on the right track however with 12 `?` chars. Do `dir /help`. I think there is a `/R` or similar for recursize search. Parsing the output is still a headache. D

Answer (score 2):

Use the `FORFILES` command:

```
FORFILES /M ???????????* /C "CMD /C DEL @file"
```

As Andrew has pointed out, the `find` syntax is correct for *nix, but not Windows. The `find` command in Windows, however, serves a different purpose; it searches for a text inside files.

And note: While logic would suggest it, don't do `DEL ???????????*`. [The Windows shell does not interpret `?` the way you'd expect](http://www.thefriendlycoder.com/2011/11/24/batch-file-gotcha-question-mark-wildcard/). This is equivalent to `DEL *.*`.

Answer (score 2):

This is not quite as convenient as StvnW's FORFILES solution, but it should perform faster. FORFILES can be quite slow.

```
for /f "eol=: delims=" %F in ('dir /b /a-d^|findstr ...........') do @del "%F"
```

Double up the percents if used within a batch script.

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct syntax for the *unix* find command. In a batch file though you're working with [a totally different find command](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490906.aspx).

Unfortunately this is only half an answer since I'm not sure what you should do instead. :(